# How it is working bool = DBConnection.getFTPConnection().storeFile(hostDir, input);

Tags: java, database, connection, database-connection, ftp-server

i am using this method to store the file.From computer to server but when i use this i am facing exception.
 1.  Software caused connection abort: recv failed
2. Software caused connection abort: socket write error
3. org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamException: IOException caught while copying. 
 i don't now how to solve that. please help me

Comment: PLease post more of your code. Do you connect to FTP server before trying to store?

Comment: DBConnection.getFTPConnection().enterLocalPassiveMode();

Comment: yes i connect to ftp server using this query. and when i run to that application this is work properly but when it enter to this point they show the exeption that i told   bool = DBConnection.getFTPConnection().storeFile(hostDir, input);

Comment: Still not enough. If this is all you got, you are not connected. I don't see anything like `DBConnection.getFTPConnection.open()...` or something similar.

Comment: I have a class of DBConnection in to that the  default constructor is using to connect to ftp basic configuration

Comment: public DBConnection(){
 if(InnertnetConnection.isInternetReachable()){
 try {
  ftpClient.connect(Constants.SERVER_URL, Constants.PORT_NUMBER);
  ftpClient.setSoTimeout(Constants.connectTimeoutValue);
  ftpClient.login(Constants.SERVER_USER, Constants.SERVER_PASSWORD);
  ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
  ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
      }

Comment: and it work properly but some time they show the error .only uploading time it show that exception in downloading its work properly. both place i am useing  same DBConnection class to connect the server class

Comment: Took me some time to orientate myself. [CopyStreamException](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/io/CopyStreamException.html) is fired when any IOException occurs during upload. If you catch the CopyStreamException, you can get the original IOException and find out what is the cause.

Comment: I will wait for your Ans.

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch the exception to get more details:

```
try {
    bool result = DBConnection.getFTPConnection().storeFile(hostDir, input);
    System.out.println("Upload: " + result);
} catch (CopyStreamException ex) {
    System.out.println("CopyStreamException: " + ex.getMessage());
    System.out.println("Totaly transfered " + ex.getTotalBytesTransferred() + " bytes.");
    System.out.println("Inner IOException: " + ex.getIOException().getMessage());
}
```

This can help you find the cause of your issue.